# Why are all Rényi entropies equal for Clifford dynamics?

Tags: entanglement, clifford-group, entropy, renyi-entropies

[In this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.031016), by Adam Nahum et al., the authors trivially states that "For Clifford dynamics all Rényi entropies are equal ... " which is not trivial to me.

Is there a paper or lecture notes on why this is true or a good explanation?

Comment: see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0406168.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me report here a brief demonstration that I used to convince myself.
The R'enyi entropies are
\begin{equation*}
    S_\mathrm{A}^\alpha = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log_2 \text{Tr} (\rho_\mathrm{A}^{\alpha})
\end{equation*}
In a nutshell, this is a consequence of the reduced density matrix $\rho_{\mathrm{A}}$ being a stabilizer itself, and hence it can be written a sum over the elements of the stabilizers group $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}$. Here $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}$ indicates the stabilizer group of all stabilizers that act trivially (identity) on the B part as defined in Appendix C of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06950.pdf).
We begin with
\begin{equation}
    \rho_\mathrm{A} = \frac{|\mathcal{S}_\mathrm{A}|}{2^{|\mathrm{A}|}} \frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}|} \sum_{s\in \mathcal{S}_\mathrm{A}}s.
\end{equation}
By squaring the density matrix, we obtain:
\begin{equation}
    \rho_{\mathrm{A}}^2 = \frac{1}{2^{2 |\mathrm{A}|}} \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}} \sum_{s' \in \mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}} s s' = \frac{1}{2^{2 |\mathrm{A}|}} |\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}|\sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}} s = \frac{|\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}|}{2^{|\mathrm{A}|}} \rho_{\mathrm{A}}
\end{equation}
In the second equality we utilize the fact $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}$ is a group, hence the product between its elements generate elements within the same group, and this happens exactly $|\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}|$ times.
It is evident that in general $\rho_{\mathrm{A}}^{\alpha} = (|\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}| / 2^{|\mathrm{A}|})^{\alpha - 1} \rho_{\mathrm{A}}$.
By substituting this into the expression for the R'enyi entropy, we obtain
\begin{align*}
    S_{\mathrm{A}}^{\alpha} & = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log_2 \text{Tr} \bigg[ \bigg(\frac{|\mathcal{S}|}{ 2^{|\mathrm{A}|}} \bigg)^{\alpha - 1} \rho_{\mathrm{\alpha}} \bigg] \\
    & =  \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log_2 \bigg(\frac{|\mathcal{S}_\mathrm{A}}{ 2^{|\mathrm{A}|}} \bigg)^{\alpha - 1} \text{Tr} \rho_{\mathrm{A}} \\
    & = |\mathrm{A}| - \log_2|\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{A}}| \\
\end{align*}
which is exactly the result we achieved in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06950.pdf) and similar as [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08092.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

In stabilizer states (which are the states produced by clifford dynamics) the entanglement spectrum is flat, i.e., all the non-zero Schmidt coefficients are equal. Starting from there, it is straightforwards to check that all Renyi entropies are equal, namely $\log D$, where $D$ is the number of non-zero Schmidt coefficients.